# Como verificar se existe um determinado numero numa variável php?

Tags: php, variáveis, preg-match

Então eu estava dando uma pesquisada, procurando alguma função do php que verifica se um determinado numero existe dentro de uma variável. E eu encontrei a preg_match(). Só que tem um porem, o php da um erro e pelo que eu intendi ela não  funciona com números só com outros caracteres alguem pode me ajudar?

código:

```
$numeros = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"; 
preg_match(1,$numeros);
```

Erro:

> `Warning: preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: você precisa usar os delimitadores...

Comment: As funções a abaixo funcionaram. muitos obrigado.

Answer (score 8):

Utilize os delimitadores dentro da string que você esta procurando:

```
$numeros = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"; 
preg_match('/1/',$numeros); // Você pode usar / ou #
```

Answer (score 5):

Pode-se usar o `strpos()`. Mas tem que ser encarada como *string*.

```
$numeros = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"; 
$temNumero = strpos($numeros, '1');

if($temNumero >= 0) // ou ($temNumero > -1)
   echo 'Achou';
else 
   echo 'Não achou';
```

Ou usando `preg_match_all()`, numa expressão regular.

```
$re = '/[1]/';
$str = '123456';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

if(count($matches) > 0)
   echo 'Achou';
else
   echo 'Não achou';
```

Comment: A primeira solução tem muitas limitações, principalmente porque a função `strpos` retornará 0 para o número 1 e quando testado no `if`, o teste falhará.

Comment: Corrigido, Anderson. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strrpos.php) ou [strripos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strripos.php) se não retornar `falso` foi encontrado:

```
int strrpos ( string $haystack , string $needle [, int $offset ] )
```

Exemplo no seu código:

```
<?php

    $numeros = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"; 

    $result = strrpos ($numeros, "8");

    if (is_int($result))
    {
        echo 'encontrado';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'não encontrou';
    }
```